# React agrid flash first row in the grid when only one record is present in grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I want to flash first row of the grid. My grid has only one row. I want to load data in grid and also flash the cell. I have sample code.If you notice method `onInsertOne`. It does not work very first time but it works when we click the button second time. How to flash cell for the first time.

```js
        let items = [];
        gridAPI.forEachNode(function(rowNode, index) { 
            items.push(rowNode); --> row Node is empty for the first time.
        });
```

I also tried getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0) but no luck.

```js
import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

import {useState, useRef, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback} from 'react';
import {createOneCarRecord} from './carFactory';

let gridAPI = null;
export const AppHighLightFirstRow = () => {
    const gridRef = useRef();
    const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(null);
    let cars = [];
    
    const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
        { field: 'type', sortable: true },
        { field: 'year' },
        { field: 'color' },
        { field: 'price' }
    ])

    const getRowId = useCallback( params => {
        return params.data.id;
      });

    const onInsertOne = useCallback( ()=> {
        const newRecord = createOneCarRecord();
        let cars = [newRecord];
        setRowData(cars);

        let items = [];
        gridAPI.forEachNode(function(rowNode, index) { 
            items.push(rowNode);
        });

        console.log(`Items Length to highLight =${items.length}`,items)
        gridAPI.flashCells({ rowNodes: items , flashDelay: 2000, fadeDelay: 1000});

      });

      const onGridReady = (params) => {
        params.api.hideOverlay();
        gridAPI = params.api;
      }

    return (
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <div><button onClick={onInsertOne}>Insert One</button></div>
        <AgGridReact ref={gridRef}
          enableCellChangeFlash={true}
          getRowId={getRowId}
          rowSelection={'multiple'}
          rowData={rowData} 
          animateRows={true} 
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          />
          </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onRowDataUpdated` event

```js
       <AgGridReact 
          ...
          onRowDataUpdated={({api}) => {
             const items = [];
             api.forEachNode(function(rowNode) { 
                items.push(rowNode);
             });

             console.log(`Items Length to highLight =${items.length}`,items)
             api.flashCells({ rowNodes: items , flashDelay: 2000, fadeDelay: 1000});
          }}
       />
```